# txt mime type allows .js or .r files

Tags: php, laravel

With the below validation rule, it accepts not only txt files, also allows `.js` and `.r` files.

```
$request->validate([
    'file' => 'required|mimes:doc,docx,xlx,xlsx,ppt,pptx,csv,pdf,jpg,jpeg,png,gif,odt,ods,odp,txt|max:10240'
]);
```

How can I make it only accept real txt files?

Comment: Could you try `text/plain` instead of `txt`?

Comment: Use [mimetypes](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-mimetypes) instead

Comment: @aykut  yes its not working

Comment: @RajeshSharma `mimes` doesn't work with `text/plain`, use `mimetypes` instead

Comment: @brombeer minetypes text/plain also allows .js or .r file extesions